# Broadcasting a HashMap in Flink

Tags: java, hashmap, apache-flink

I am using `Flink v.1.4.0`.

I am working with the `DataSet` API and one of the things I want to try is very similar to how broadcast variables are used in `Apache Spark`.

Practically, I want to apply a map function on a `DataSet`, go through each of the elements in the `DataSet` and search for it in a `HashMap`; if the search element is present in the Map then retrieve the respective value.

The `HashMap` is very big and I don't know if (since I haven't even built my solution) it needs to be `Serializable` to be transmitted and used by all workers concurrently.

In general, the solution I have in mind would look like this:

```
Map<String, T> hashMap = new ... ;

DataSet<Point> points = env.readCsv(...);

points
  .map(point -> hashMap.getOrDefault(point.getId, 0))
  ...
```

but I don't know if this would work or if it is efficient in any way. After doing a bit of searching I found a much better example [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLINK/Variables+Closures+vs.+Broadcast+Variables) according to which one can us `Broadcast` variables in `Flink` to broadcast a `List` as follows:

```
DataSet<Point> points = env.readCsv(...);

DataSet<Centroid> centroids = ... ; // some computation

points.map(new RichMapFunction<Point, Integer>() {

    private List<Centroid> centroids;

    @Override
    public void open(Configuration parameters) {
        this.centroids = getRuntimeContext().getBroadcastVariable("centroids");
    }

    @Override
    public Integer map(Point p) {
        return selectCentroid(centroids, p);
    }

}).withBroadcastSet("centroids", centroids);
```

However, `.getBroadcastVariable()` seems to only work with a `List`.

- Can someone provide an alternative solution with a `HashMap`?
- How would that solution work?
- What is the most efficient way to go about solving this?
- Could one use a Flink Managed State to do something similar to how broadcast variables are used? How?
- Finally, can I attempt multiple `mappings` with multiple broadcast variables in a pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where do the values of `hashMap` come from? Two other possible solutions:

1. Reinitialise/recreate/regenerate `hashMap` in each instance of your filtering/mapping operator separately in [open](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/api/java/org/apache/flink/api/common/functions/RichFunction.html#open-org.apache.flink.configuration.Configuration-) method. Probably more efficient per record, but duplicates initialisation logic.
2. Create two `DataSet`, one for `hashMap` values, second for `points` and [join](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/batch/index.html#dataset-transformations) those two `DataSet`s using [desired join strategy](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/batch/dataset_transformations.html#join-algorithm-hints). As an analogy, what you are trying to do could be expressed by SQL query `SELECT * FROM points p, hashMap h WHERE h.key = p.id`.

Comment: You are right--this makes perfect sense; it even explains why hashMaps are not part of the broadcast variable API. Should have thought of it myself ... Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad I could be helpful :)